# X-axis range changes based on hidden Series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have 2 Series on one graph. Only one series can show at a time but the hidden graph affects the range on the x-axis.

The data is dynamically generated via PHP but here is 2 fiddles to show what I mean:

[Fiddle With Changed Scale and Hidden Data](http://jsfiddle.net/k7bctryw/4/)

[Fiddle With removed Hidden Data and correct scale](http://jsfiddle.net/k7bctryw/3/)

This code snippet is to ensure that only one series can be shown at any given time.

```
events: {
    show: function () {
        var chart = this.chart,
            series = chart.series,
            i = series.length,
            otherSeries;
            var seriesName = this['options']['name'];
            chart.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
                text: seriesName
            });

        while (i--) {
            otherSeries = series[i];
            if (otherSeries != this && otherSeries.visible) {
                otherSeries.hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why the graph with the hidden data shows until 16:00 but the graph without any additional data shows until the last data point at 15:38

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Highcharts is taking into account the `pointRange` of the series with the largest `pointRange` (although it is hidden) and displaying the x-axis based on that. The range of your "Calls/Hour" series is 1 hour, so it makes sure that if that series had a point at the very end, it would still have room to show.

I'm not sure if there's any elegant way of solving this, but a bit of a "hack" in your case is to change the `pointRange` of all series to that of the currently showing one.

My crude implementation of this has three changes to your code:

1. Your series that are `visible: false` by default also get `pointRange: 1` so they don't disrupt the x-axis range for the only visible series.
2. When the chart has been created we store the correct point range of each series for future reference, for example with the callback function:

   ```
   $('#callFrequencyGraph').highcharts({
       // Options...
   }, function(event) {
       var series = this.series;

       // Store the correct point ranges
       for(var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
           series[i].update({
               historicalPointRange: (series[i].closestPointRange ? series[i].closestPointRange : 3600000)
           }, false);
           this.redraw();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Extend your `events.legendItemClick` function to update all series `pointRange` to that of the series which will be showing after the click is completed:

   ```
   legendItemClick: function() {
       if(this.visible){
            return false;
       }
       else {
           var series = this.chart.series;

           for(var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
               series[i].update({ 
                   pointRange: this.options.historicalPointRange 
               }, false);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7bctryw/8/) for the result of all these changes.
Edit: jsFiddle Update for bug

Comment: I like it enough, but it's rather hackish. I will wait for another answer to come around. If one doesn't come in decent time, I'll select this an best answer.

Comment: Yes, hopefully there's something more elegant. I'd like to see it :)

Comment: Ondkloss answer is correct, you should use pointRange (60000).

Comment: `Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute x="NaN" highcharts.js:54 `
`Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute width="NaN" highcharts.js:54 `
Error occurs when I have only one point on hourly
http://jsfiddle.net/k7bctryw/6/

Comment: Good catch. Without two points there is no `closestPointRange`. Immediate fix would be something like `historicalPointRange: (series[i].closestPointRange ? series[i].closestPointRange : 1)`, but it does not give the original look of the chart. I'll look at it some more.

Comment: `historicalPointRange: (series[i].closestPointRange ? series[i].closestPointRange : 3600000)` Looks best because it fills the chart how it would normally if there was only one point (my JSON fixes the issue after 30 seconds so I could see the pointRange after JSON.)

Comment: Found another bug:
http://jsfiddle.net/k7bctryw/10/
Upon updating Data dynamically, the x-axis scale changes.

Comment: Hm. What do you mean "scale changes"? From what I see you replace all your points with a single point in each series. How did you expect this to look?

Comment: On any `setData` with 1 point, it puts `08:00:00.000` instead of showing `7:59 8:00 8:01` Same exact data.